# Server side proxy for divshot not rendering JSON api in Ember app

Tags: ember.js, rails-api, divshot

I can start my ember/rails server by running ember serve --proxy http://localhost:3000.

I have create a divshot account in order to push this app to a production server but am having trouble passing in the url to my json api.

```
//divshot.json
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "root": "./dist",
  "routes": {
    "/tests": "tests/index.html",
    "/tests/**": "tests/index.html",
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "origin": "https://railsapi.herokuapp.com/"
  }
}

//environment.js
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'project-name',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
    // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
    // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {

  }

  return ENV;
};
```

How can I push an app to divshot and use the api I have hosted elsewhere?

**ember-cli 1.8.1** - [link to project in question](https://github.com/STEAMRole/diversified_voices_client/tree/divshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally didn’t realise Divshot had this service. Awesome.

Looking at [the docs](http://docs.divshot.com/services/proxy), it seems you need to put the proxy under a named key.

In their example it’s `"api"`:

```
{
  "proxy": {
    "api": {
      "origin":"https://api.my-app.com",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      "cookies": false,
      "timeout": 30
    }
  }
}
```

And access it via a special URL of the form `/__/proxy/{NAME}/{PATH}`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/__/proxy/api/users/123',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

---

**EDIT:**

I left out the actual configuration of your Ember app.

You’ll want to setup API prefix in `config/environment.js`.

Working locally in development the prefix will be `''` and on Divshot it will be `/__/proxy/api`.

In `config/environment.js` I like to do this:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  // Snip...

  ENV.API_PREFIX: process.env.API_PREFIX || '',
};
```

You can then use this value in `app/adapters/application.js` like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: config.apiUrl
});
```

And specify `API_PREFIX` on the command line like this:

```
$ API_PREFIX="/__/proxy/api" ember build
$ divshot push
```

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: You could also point your Ember app directly at the Rails app on Heroku.

(`API_PREFIX=https://railsapi.herokuapp.com ember build`)

This means you’ll have to correctly configure the CORS headers in your Rails app.

Comment: when you say configure the CORS do you mean creating the "api" namespace in the rails app?

Comment: No, I mean configuring the app to server to right CORS headers. I tend to use this Gem: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Comment: Did this answer work out for OP? Divshot cofounder here, happy to help if I can (though not super-familiar with Ember's config stuff).

Comment: This worked though I had to set the `config.apiUrl` manually. Definitely love the speed at whichI could get things deployed on divshot once I updated the config files